# Using position() to select a specific node while in a for-each loop in xslt not returning expected results

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I realize this code isn't the cleanest, but properly refactoring it unfortunately isn't an option.

The issue is that I would expect `position()` on the second iteration to return a true value. But when using `position()` it never returns true, as expected on the second iteration.

But if I hard code the selection values, it returns the expected result. Here is an example:

```
<root>
  <MainProducts>
    <MainProduct>
      <Published>0</Published>
    </MainProduct>
    <MainProduct>
      <Published>1</Published>
    </MainProduct>
  </MainProducts>
  <SubProducts>
    <SubProduct>
      <IsDefault>1</IsDefault>
    </SubProduct>
    <SubProduct>
      <IsDefault>0</IsDefault>
    </SubProduct>
  </SubProducts>
</root>
```

XML content:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/SubProducts/SubProduct">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Always returns false
    console.log("Dynamic position " + <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> + " IsDefault: " + ( <xsl:value-of select="/root/MainProducts/MainProduct[position()]/Published" /> == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
  </script>
</xsl:for-each>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Returns false, but expected to return true on second iteration.
  console.log("Hard coded position 1 IsDefault: " + ( <xsl:value-of select="/root/MainProducts/MainProduct[1]/Published" /> == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));

  // Returns true
  console.log("Hard coded position 2 IsDefault: " + ( <xsl:value-of select="/root/MainProducts/MainProduct[2]/Published" /> == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
</script>
```

Here is the exact console output:

```
Dynamic position 1 IsDefault: false
Dynamic position 2 IsDefault: false
Hard coded position 1 IsDefault: false
Hard coded position 2 IsDefault: true
```

What am I missing here that `position()` isn't selecting the node properly?

Comment: "properly refactoring it unfortunately isn't an option". Yes it is. When you start saying refactoring isn't an option, you are on the road to hell.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree that it is a road to hell. But when working with a large system, refactoring major sections of the software to resolve a minor issue like this just isn't worth the risk. So unfortunately due to the risk of bringing down an already functioning system, it isn't an option.

Comment: Many times I've been in the same position and argued the same way. It was only postponing the inevitable disaster.

Comment: The problem is, they won't believe despite all the evidence that NOT refactoring will cost more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Always returns false
    console.log("Dynamic position " + 
   <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> + 
    " IsDefault: " + 
      ( <xsl:value-of select="/root/MainProducts/MainProduct[position()]/Published" /> 
        == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
  </script>
```

In the above code `MainProduct[position()]` is equivalent to `MainProduct[true()]` )don't forget that `position()` is context-sensitive!

So, you are actually evaluating:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/MainProducts/MainProduct/Published" />
```

and this outputs always the string value of the first `Published` element that is selected by the XPath expression -- it happens to be `0`.

**Correct code**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Always returns false
    console.log("Dynamic position " + 
   <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> + 
    " IsDefault: " + 
      ( <xsl:value-of select=
             "/root/MainProducts/MainProduct[position()=$vPos]/Published" /> 
        == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
  </script>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/SubProducts/SubProduct">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Dynamic position " +
       <xsl:value-of select="position()" /> +
        " IsDefault: " +
          ( <xsl:value-of select=
             "/*/MainProducts/MainProduct
                         [position()=$vPos]/Published" />
            == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
      </script>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <MainProducts>
        <MainProduct>
            <Published>0</Published>
        </MainProduct>
        <MainProduct>
            <Published>1</Published>
        </MainProduct>
    </MainProducts>
    <SubProducts>
        <SubProduct>
            <IsDefault>1</IsDefault>
        </SubProduct>
        <SubProduct>
            <IsDefault>0</IsDefault>
        </SubProduct>
    </SubProducts>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Dynamic position " +
       1 +
        " IsDefault: " +
          ( 0
            == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("Dynamic position " +
       2 +
        " IsDefault: " +
          ( 1
            == 1 ? "true" : "false" ));
      </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Dimitre. I was unaware that `position()` is equivalent to `true()`. I'll have to read up on more documentation on `position`. Thanks again!

Comment: @BenRecord, You are welcome. Actually, in `someName[position()]` the value of position is the position of `someName` in the document-ordered sequence of `someName` elements that are all siblings and children of the same parent. So, this value is generally a positive integer. Within a predicate this is either evaluated as a boolean (and converted to `true()`, or this is evaluated as the required position (I am not exactly sure which of these two is really the correct one), and as this is the same position, the same element is selected -- so it is equivalent to having `true()` specified there.